# No DbContext was found in assembly 'ProjectName.Web'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, command-line-interface, abp

I'm trying to add the Volo.Blogging module for ABP.io MVC project and I get the '***No DbContext was found in assembly 'ProjectName.Web'***. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.' error.

The bash commands:

```
abp new ProjectName
cd ProjectName
abp add-module Volo.Blogging -sp ./src/ProjectName.Web/ProjectName.Web.csproj
```

I'm on macOS Catalina, .NET Core 3.1.100, abp cli 1.1.2, Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `.DbMigrator` project as the startup project instead:

```sh
abp add-module Volo.Blogging -sp ./src/ProjectName.DbMigrator/ProjectName.DbMigrator.csproj
```

References:

- https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/2368
- https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-AspNetCore-MVC-Template#using-the-dbmigrator-application

Comment: Thank you aaron for your quick reply. Unfortunately, setting the path to the DbMigrator csproj does not work. I'm still getting the No DbContext error. I've also tried with the EntityFrameworkCore and EntityFrameworkCore.DbMigrations csproj without success.

Comment: How about not specifying?

Comment: Now I'm getting 'No project was found. Change the current working directory or use the --project option.' error.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Did you `cd ProjectName` after `abp new ProjectName`?

Comment: Yes I've cd in the solution folder...same result. I will try the same test on my Windows machine and get back with the result. Thanks again aaron.

Answer (score 0):

you must to check the library class for example avoid any name reserved in the .NET like as ( EF, Web ....)

**Change the Library Class Name From EF**

[issue EF Library class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzgnk.png)

**To Article.EF**

[Solution Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxr5f.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.